# Nginx isn't logging to the spot specified in the config file

Tags: nginx

When I look at my config, it says it should be logging to:

```
/var/log/nginx/access.log
```

but instead, it's logging to:

```
/home/admin/web/example.com/logs/example.com.log
```

even when I turn the access log off, which is a big issue - I'm worried it's not going to cap and take up a huge amount of space!

This is a problem, because I cannot turn the access log off and I'm worried it's going to take up too much space on my hard drive - and I don't know where the preference is set. It isn't set to log to that spot in nginx.conf anywhere. Using Linux CentOS 6.7 64-bit

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, when you use VestaCP nginx has two config files, in different spots.
The other one is located in home/admin/conf/web
This was the file I needed to modify to prevent the other access log from being created. Also check httpd.conf in the same folder.